# Mercurial Alias in Python

Tags: python, mercurial

I have an existing mercurial alias (for closing and merging feature branches) written in bash. The problem is, that my colleagues with windows machines cannot use it. Mercurial is already delivered with Python, so question is whether it is possible to call python code in the alias. Then it would be OS independent.

```sh
[alias]
close-feature = ![ -z "$1" ] && echo "You have to specify the issue number!" && exit 1; \
        if hg branches | grep -q "fb-$1"; \
            then $HG up fb-$1; $HG commit -m 'Close branch fb-$1.' --close-branch; $HG pull; $HG up default; $HG merge fb-$1; $HG commit -m 'Merge branch fb-$1 -> default.'; \
            else echo "The branch fb-$1 does NOT exist!"; \
        fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> question is whether it is possible to call python code in the alias

Without standalone Python - no, AFAIK. You can write Mercurial extension in Python, which will add needed command - and extension will be executed in pure Mercurial's environment

Comment: For those who want to implement this, the mercurial API could be handy http://nullege.com/codes/search/mercurial